# Shell script errors?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, scripts, postfix

I am trying to create an interactive bash shell script to make it easier to install and configure a postfix mail server,But have them still enter the commands and then the shell run them, but I keep getting this error and I don't know why.

These two lines are giving me the error "Too many arguments"

```
if test $VAR1 = sudo apt-get install postfix
```

and

```
until test $VAR1 = sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote the arguments to `test` to stop them 'breaking' on whitespace, i.e. if

```
$ var1="sudo apt-get install postfix"
```

then

```
$ if test $var1 = sudo apt-get install postfix; then echo "Match"; fi
bash: test: too many arguments
```

but

```
$ if test "$var1" = "sudo apt-get install postfix"; then echo "Match"; fi
Match
```

The same applies if you use the `[ ... ]` test construct

```
if [ "$var1" = "sudo apt-get install postfix" ]; then echo "Match"; fi
```

As an aside, it's recommended not to use all-caps for your variable names - all-caps are generally reserved for system variables.